# Android: passing parameters through url

Tags: php, android, sql-server, http-post

I want to insert some data into a database using a http post request.
My post.php page is:

```
      if(trim($_GET['param1'])!="" && trim($_GET['param2'])!="" && trim($_GET['param3'])!="" && trim($_GET['param4'])!="" && trim($_GET['param5'])!="")
{
    $connectionInfo = array(  "UID" => $DB_USER,  "PWD" => $DB_PASS, "Database"=>$DB_DATABASE );
    $con = sqlsrv_connect($DB_SERVER,$connectionInfo);
    if(!$con)
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
    }
    $query="INSERT INTO Table (param1,param2,param3,param4,param5) VALUES (
            '".$_GET['param1']."',
            ".$_GET['param2'].",
            ".$_GET['param3'].",
            '".$_GET['param4']."',
            ".$_GET['param5'].")";
            [...]
```

and in order to send data, I append all the parameters to the url, like: `http://<myip>/MySite/post.php?param2=10&param3=8&param1=2012-12-01 13:00:00&param4=Name&param5=80`

and everything works fine, but when I try to send my data from my Android application I could not achive my target.
How can I pass data via url?
In Android I've tried:

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://<Myip>/MySite/post.php");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "10"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param3", "98"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "2012-12-01 13:00:00"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param4", "Name"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param5", "50"));
    //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost)
```

and with:

```
String urlParameters = "param1=2012-12-01 13:00:00&param2=b&param3=c...";
String request = "http://<Myip>/MySite/post.php";
URL url = new URL(request); 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""  Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
connection.setUseCaches (false);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

but I always get errors.
Using second method the exception is:

```
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at  com.example.applic.applic.postData(MyApp.java:197)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at com.example.applic.applic$1.run(MyApp.java:127)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
12-17 18:08:26.617: E/AndroidRuntime(4837):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Don't run your network operations on the UI thread. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: I run my network operation inside an handler, it's not inside the main thread.

Comment: unless you have started handler in another thread, it will still run on the main thread

Comment: nandeesh is right. And again, notice the name of your error: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: search networkonmainthread, to begin with (-1 for not searching this term, there are literally thousands of article on that topic). then, you are using post for get. you use _GET in PHP, which would indicate you want to receive a GET request. but you use an HttpPost and then a Post request, which indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) :

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.

means you are trying to run network operation from UI Thread so put your all network related code inside [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s `doInBackground` method and use `onPostExecute` for updating UI when `doInBackground` method execution complete

and if your are using **API LEVEL 9 or GREATER FROM 9** then add [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) in onCreate of Activity to avoid this error

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectDiskReads()
                 .detectDiskWrites()
                 .detectNetwork()  
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .build());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception. You need to move the Network request code onto another Thread or use an Asynctask.

You cannot make network requests on Main thread

Comment: Ok, but I run my postData() method inside an handler.

Comment: Handler is just a helper to run the code asynchronously, it will still run the code on main thread. You will have to create the handler in a different thread which has looper prepared, only then will it work

Comment: if we are using `API LEVEL 9 or GREATER FROM 9` then we will make network from Ui thread by using `StrictMode` and without using `Asynctask` but it's better to use `Asynctask` to make your code more reusable

Answer (score 0):

> This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread which is not allowed in android version >= 3.

To get free from this exception better way to run your code in AsyncTask:

```
class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
        //Implement Logic you want to perform in background.
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void feed) {
       //Implement logic whatever you want to perform after task complete.
    }
 }

new BackTask().execute();
```

**OR**

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```